# for what $\sigma , \tau \in \mathbb{C}$ is $f_{\sigma}f_{\tau}=f_{\sigma + \tau}$ why?

Tags: complex-analysis

For $ \sigma \in \mathbb{C}$ is

\begin{align*}
f_{\sigma}:\mathbb{C} \setminus (-\infty, 0] \rightarrow \mathbb{C}, z\rightarrow e^{\sigma \ln(z)}
\end{align*}

for what $\sigma , \tau \in \mathbb{C}$ is $f_{\sigma}f_{\tau}=f_{\sigma + \tau}$ why?

i think it means when is z^$\tau$$\sigma$=z^$\tau$+$\sigma$. is that right?

Comment: I'm not following your notation.  Is there some MathJax markup missing in the last line?

Answer (score 0):

We have $\forall \sigma,\tau \in \mathbb{C} ,\ \forall z \in \mathbb{C} \ \setminus (-\infty,0]$ that
$$\begin{align}
f_{\sigma+\tau}(z) & = e^{(\sigma+\tau)log(z)} \\
& = e^{\sigma log(z)} * e^{\tau log(z)} \\
& = f_{\sigma}(z) * f_{\tau} (z)
\end{align}$$

The second equality being by properties of the exponential function for all branches of log.

So this gives that for all $\sigma, \tau \in \mathbb{C}$, we have $f_\sigma f_\tau = f_{\sigma + \tau}$